# Android: Padding not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, padding, android-relativelayout

I want to have a padding between the description text and the switch but paddingRight property is not working. Why?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layoutLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutHeader"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/widgetShortSwitch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a long description text that should not overlay."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/widgetShortTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layoutLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutHeader"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widgetShortTextView"
            android:layout_width="0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="This is a long description text that should not overlay."
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/widgetShortSwitch"
            android:layout_width="0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.15" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome. When you add "dp" units to your layout_widths it is perfect.

Comment: Please explain what you changed and why it corrected the problem.  Was it just changing the order of the TextView and the Switch?   Why does layout_width '0' in the TextView make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell RelativeLayout that your TextView is left to your Switch.
You also need to put your TextView as alignParentLeft, so that it will start from the left.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layoutLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutHeader"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/widgetShortSwitch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a long description text that should not overlay."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/widgetShortTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/widgetShortSwitch"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```